# iOS Maps - ultra high zoom level

Tags: ios, mapkit

I notice there is a limit to high far I can zoom in using the iOS map kit. This seems to be different at different location on the map. It appears that wherever the imagery is really high res, you can zoom in closer than areas where the imagery is low res. Is there a way to manually allow for zooming in closer? Perhaps if I provide my own high res tiles? Does anyone have experience that would suggest this is possible/impossible? I have customers with really, really high resolution imagery and would like to allow them to zoom in much closer.

Comment: Are you using MapKit or Google Maps?  Your question is tagged for both.

Comment: Sorry - I am using Mapkit.